# Visualize the difference of 2 BufferedImages

Tags: java, for-loop, comparison, bufferedimage, graphics2d

I have made a function to visually compare the difference of 2 BufferedImage's by making a new image where each pixel of the first image is looped through and when a pixel is equal to the second painting a pixel in the new image.

At first this seemed to be working however after doing some tests with the function i noticed something which makes me now think it might be incorrect. When i input a image with a horizontal gradient bar for img1 and the same but vertically offset for img2 it was fully painting a mask for the gradient from the first image. However i don't think it should be doing that as those pixels should not be matching.

So for example if i input 2 BufferedImage's like this:

```
@@@@@@@@    @@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@    --------
---@---@    ---@---@
@@@----@    @@-----@
```

It might output a mask/BufferedImage like this:

```
@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@
-------@
@@@----@
```

However i was expecting it to output something like this instead:

```
@@@@@@@@
--------
---@---@
@@-----@
```

When i look it i don't see where i am going wrong but it seems there a problem somewhere. Does anyone know what i have done wrong with my function?

```
public BufferedImage MatchBIMask(BufferedImage img1, BufferedImage img2, Color background, Color match){
    int w = img1.getWidth();
    int h = img1.getHeight();
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
    g.setColor(background);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    g.setColor(match);

    for (int row=0; row < h; row++){
        for (int col=0; col < w; col++){
            int rgb1 = img1.getRGB(col, row);
            int rgb2 = img2.getRGB(col, row);
            if (rgb1 == rgb2) {
                // Match code here
                g.drawRect(col, row, 0, 0); // Draw pixel
            } 
        }
    }

    return img;
}
```

Edit:

The way i am getting the 2 BufferedImages that i compare is with the following code:

```
BufferedImage img = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(x, y, w, h)); // Rectangle Area
```

I do not know if that code takes alpha into account or not though.

Comment: You may have images with different alpha channels, to compare just the color, try masking the RGB values with 0x00FFFFFF before comparing.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and either include a small (WxH & Kb) pair of images or generate them in code.

Comment: I have updated my post with the way i was getting 2 BufferedImages to compare, they were simply 32x32 captures of the screen with AWT. @Durandal, thanks i am not sure how to do this however as i am quite new to Java, if possible it would be very helpful to have a code example of how to mask the RGB values like that.

Comment: The image from Robot may have an alpha channel if the desktop is set to 32bit depth, but it should contain a constant value then. So its most likely not your problem. *Masking* in my earlier comment meant ensuring the alpha channel is not considered in the comparison, in code this would be written as (rgb1 & 0x00FFFFFFF) == (rgb2 & 0x00FFFFFF) instead rgb1 == rgb2. However I believe thats not causing your problem here.

Comment: I just tried this but using: if ((rgb1 & 0x00FFFFFFF) == (rgb2 & 0x00FFFFFF)){ seems to output no pixel matches even when they are aligned at the same positions.

Comment: There is a typo in my earlier comment, the left value contains one 'F' to many. It should have been 0x00 FF FF FF (*six* F's) on both sides. But still, I think your problem is not caused by alhpa channel when you obtain the images using Robot.